# Custom login with facebook button. Not getting info other than name and UserID

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get email from my logged in user using Facebook SDK. Here are 2 of my login methods

```
-(void)loginButtonClicked {
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]
 fromViewController:self
 handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Process error");
     } else if (result.isCancelled) {
         NSLog(@"Cancelled");
     } else {

         [self getFBUSerData];
         NSLog(@"Logged in");
     }
 }];
}


- (void) getFBUSerData {

if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken != nil) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
         }
     }];
    }
}
```

The result in the log:

```
(lldb) po result 
{
id = 42357***4506554;
name = "Fname Lname";
}
```

But no email or friends list. Any help how to get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the parameters you need to get in getFBUserData().

Something like this:

```
- (void) getFBUSerData {

if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken != nil) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"] forKeys:@[@"fields"]];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:dict]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
         }
     }];        }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thats real clever of me. Thanks!